# How can I make the tables generated in R markdown pdf look prettier?

Tags: r, r-markdown

When I knit a pdf using R Markdown, it generates (tidy)tables that look like this:

```
## # A tidytable: 44,593 x 5
## Sequence Order Lect Category ipa
## <chr> <int> <chr> <fct> <chr>
## 1 pw 1 Gurani O p
## 2 dw 1 Gurani O d
## 3 ɡw 1 Gurani O ɡ
## 4 kw 1 Gurani O k
## 5 qw 1 Gurani O q
## 6 fw 1 Gurani O f
## 7 xw 1 Gurani O x
## 8 sw 1 Gurani O s
## 9 ʃw 1 Gurani O ʃ
## 10 zw 1 Gurani O z
## # ... with 44,583 more rows
## # i Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Which is not very readable.

How can I customize the Markdown pdf to create tables that are easier to read, especially with straightly aligned columns?

Comment: It would help make your question more specific if you included an example of the table you are unhappy with including the programming problems you are having in achieving the appearance you require. There are several packages which could be used to create tables in `rmarkdown` with a pdf output for example `knitr::kable` and  `kableExtra`. The R Markdown Cookbook includes a list of other packages for table formatting. https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/

Answer (score 0):

Set the df_print to kable.

```
pdf_document:
    df_print: kable
```